# How to chelate magnesium oxide and l-lysine

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Given magnesium oxide and l-lysine dissolved in water. What needs to happen so that both form a chelate inside the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but too long for a comment.

First recognize what is really in solution.  Magnesium oxide does not dissolve in water.  It reacts to give magnesium hydroxide, which in turn is only sparingly soluble in water alone but could react with the acidic lysine.  You should proceed as if your solution had magnesium ions and lysine anion -- because after the reactions involving the magnesium oxide that is what you end up with!